# How to modify the value of a JavaScript map?

Tags: javascript

My Javascript map object maps each key to an array.  I have an issue with updating the array.

I tried to use a javascript object only.

```
const temp = {"map":[1], "what":[1,2]};
temp["what"].push(3);
console.log(temp);
```

It works but I still want to know whether there is a way to update the map object.

My original code is like this:

```
const temp = new Map();
temp.set("what", [1]);
temp["what"].push(2);
console.log(temp);
```

expect: {"what"=>[1,2]}

actual result:

`VM6258:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:12`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `get` with `Map`, i.e.

```
temp.get("what").push(2)
```

Comment: Oh, I see.  temp["what"] is not allowed here.  Thanks!